# nm-applet crash sometimes when use CDMA

Tags: 13.04, network-manager, 13.10

i have had a problem since 13.04 and seems that problem persist to 13.10 too. 
This problem is described pretty extensive [in this thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150112&p=12819729#post12819729) and [in  bug #1179070 on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1179070).

Does anyone of you have any idea what could be? Only can restart nm-applet from terminal but all link seems to be corrupted.

This is the output:

```
(nm-applet:2478): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed
*** Error in `nm-applet': corrupted double-linked list: 0x098a2738 ***
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem & wrote my own version of nm-applet

http://geek.rohitkalhans.com/2013/10/nm-applet-crash-in-ubuntu-1304-raring.html